# Define linking options in C++ source file

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

I'm in a very weird position where I am not able to modify the makefile, just the source code, but need to link other libraries. Is there any way to specify a linking option (e.g. -lcuda) in the source file or somehow get it to compile? I'm using GCC 4.8. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reviving this to explain the problem better and the solution I came up with. This was for an assignment for a CS class where we needed to optimize various math kernels and algorithms as much as possible. The rules were pretty much "anything goes" as long as everything was contained in the source file. You couldn't edit anything else including the makefile, environment, or other source files.

My solution was to make and compile my own, separate, executable that used CUDA and include the binary in my source file. The source file would execute the binary, then communicate with it through pipes.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use `LDFLAGS` environment variable to add necessary options.

For example:

```
$ LDFLAGS=-lcuda make
```